# Javascript output of an array with variables and html code

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, variables, output

first thanks for you help and support!

My question is how can i correctly make a correct output of html code with variables into.
I´m working with jquery and jquery.mobile.

I´m getting from a php results of an database seperated with "," and splitted to an javascript array (works) but I´m not able to output these results correctly to an dynamically working list... they have to be in a list with links and jquery look... but it just show me a list with images without the link and without jquery also it don´t stop to load.
My internet research don´t gave me the help I need and I don´t know how to solve this.
(Because I want to use PhoneGap, I can´t use php in this part)

Here is my code fragment (just the important things):

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <link rel="stylesheet"  href="css/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.css" />

    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>

    <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.js"></script>


</head>
<body>

                <div id="result">
            <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.post("Test.php",
    {
      q:"Value2ask",
    },
    function(data){

var share=data.split(",");

            if (share.length>=1){
            for(var i = 0; i < share.length; i++)
             {

            var dynlist = dynlist + ('<li><form id="'+share[i]+'" method="POST" action="Next.php" data-ajax="false">'+
            '<input id="id" name="id" value="'+share[i]+'" type="hidden"/> </form>'+
            '<img src="images/pic.png" class="img'+share[i]+'" align="LEFT" width="38" height="38" />'+
            '<a onclick="document.getElementById('+share[i]+').submit();" data-transition="slide" data-ajax="false">&nbsp; '+share[i]+'</a></li>');


            } 
            return document.innerHTML(dynlist);
            } else { 
            var dynlist =   ('<li> <a data-rel="back" data-role="button" data-icon="back" data-ajax="false">No results, click to get back </a></li>');
            return document.innerHTML(dynlist);
            }


    });
});  
</script></div></body></html>
```

I also tried it with document.write (same result like innerHTML) and some other versions like document.write with every single line .... 
No positive results ... please help :)
Thanks!

EDIT: I get the correct code that I want but it don´t show me the result i want... (the link is not working for example and there is no jQuery in the list ...)

Comment: are you getting any errors ?

Comment: @EnterJQ no the web-developer console stops at the post command ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay there was just missing an listview refresh to get the jquery mobile style ... and missing ' for the getElementbyID part. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

You have `var dynlist` in for loop of success response.

correct that with

```
var dynlist;

for(conditions)
{
    dynlist += "code";
}
```

and instead of returning return document.innerHTML(dynlist); you can use `.html()`,`.text()` or `.attr()` or `.append()` jQuery methods to add your dynlist to html DOM.

**Example**

```
$(documet).append(dynlist);
$('div#result').append(dynlist);
```

Comment: doesn't work ... it shows me nearly the same like before ... but thanks for my error that i got the var in my loop...

Comment: okay i got it so that i got the correct html code in js, and it is also shown. But there the jquery style missing ... it looks like these: http://jsfiddle.net/hYQm4/32/ (but noramlly this list should got a jquery style and also links to click ...

Comment: Okay I solved it! Where was just the listview refresh missing! Now I got the jquery mobile style but the button doesn't work (no action)... somebody an idea?